# jQuery best way to write to div with a var

Tags: jquery

Looking for the best way to get html data to a var and back to another div.

Here are the two lines that 'work', that is, they display the correct data, however, 
the alert following this code does not fire. So I am thinking there muse be an error.

```
var pFrame = window.parent.$("#myDiv");
$(pFrame).html( data ); // Gets and displays correct data
```

The Full code, or more of it:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) 
{
    alert("Got Data!");

    $.get( "../sortImages.php", function( data ) 
    {
        alert("Works");

        var pFrame = window.parent.$("#myDiv");
        $(pFrame).html( data ); // Gets and displays correct data

        alert("Does Not work");

    });

    // etc...
```

Comment: Learn to use your browser's developer tools and step through your code.

Comment: Any errors in your console? This is clearly just some failed call, or some other syntax error. Use DevTools, available in all major browsers.

Comment: check console: place before alert `console.log(data, pFrame);`; also look for other console errors on page load and method use

Comment: [How to use Google Chrome's Console Panel](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/google-chrome-dev-tools-how-to-use-the-console-panel/)